# Is there any method to automatically load webpack external files?

Tags: javascript, webpack, commonjs, externals

I organize my frontend project with commonjs like `var $ = require('jquery');` and use webpack to bundle entry js files. I can use webpack's "externals" to exclude some third-party libraries like jquery, angular or others into the final bundle and i have to add some script tags to the html to load these files. Is there any method to automatically load these external files instead of adding script tags manually in the html file?

Answer (score 1):

Webpack is a module **bundler** not a javascript loader. It package files from local disk and don't load files from the web (except its own chunks).

Use a javascript loader, i. e. [script.js](https://github.com/ded/script.js)

```
var $script = require("scriptjs");
$script("//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.9/angular.min.js", function() {
// ...
});
```

> For more information please refer to this issue on Webpack repo: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/150